# How can I use Spatial Indexes for timestamps (non-spatial 1d data)?

Tags: mysql, spatial, timestamp, range-types

I'm using MySQL 8.0. I have some table containing TIMESTAMP column and I need to select within TIMESTAMP range:

```
SELECT *
FROM t_tbl
WHERE ts BETWEEN @someDate1 AND @someDate2
```

I want to make this query as fast as possible so I decide to try GEOMETRY trick. First of all I add some magik geometry column:

```
ALTER TABLE t_tbl
  ADD COLUMN geom_ts GEOMETRY NOT NULL
  GENERATED ALWAYS AS (Point(TO_SECONDS(ts),0)) STORED;
ALTER TABLE t_tbl ADD SPATIAL INDEX IDX_g_i (geom_ts);
```

So `ts` momentum is really a point onto X (time) axis. Now to check ts is in some range I'm using such geometry expression:

```
SELECT *
FROM t_tbl
WHERE MBRCONTAINS(LineString(point(@someDate1,0),point(@someDate2,0)), geom_ts)
```

This works but EXPLAIN doesn't show me any spatial index usage - it performs tablescan...

Comment: I'm not sure about this, but maybe the index is not used because MBRContains already uses the "Minimum bounding rectangle" of your line. And by the way, your query checks if  a geometry is contained in the "Minimum Bounding Rectangle" and not the line itself. Or maybe the index is not used because you are creating a geometry (line between two points) and the resulting geometry doesn't have an index.

Answer (score 1):

`TIMESTAMP`, `DATETIME`, `INT`, `FLOAT`, `DECIMAL`, etc are effectively "numbers".  Numbers can be ordered/searched/etc with ordinary `BTREE` indexes.  There is no need for `SPATIAL` for such one-dimensional quantities.

For date-like quantities, I like to do:

```
WHERE ts >= '2018-02-23'
  AND ts  < '2018-02-23' + INTERVAL 3 WEEK

INDEX(ts)
```

This avoids dealing with leap years, kludges like '23:59:59', inclusive/exclusive (not the careful choice of inequality operators), etc.

Answer (score 0):

You have two issues likely with this,

- Floating point rounding errors
- `MBRContains` is not likely what you want, if you want to return true INCLUSIVE of end-points. For that I would use `MBRIntersects`.

Shy of that, I would assume this would work.